# Can't select text on double or triple click

Tags: mouse, 17.10, click-policy

I have a fresh Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS directly upgraded to 17.10 and I have an annoying behavior: when double clicking on text to select a word or triple clicking to select a paragraph, it doesn't select anything. I haven't tried to select anything before upgrading.

This is the same across applications (Firefox, LibreOffice and Terminal).

I really do not know what to look for.

I'm currently running Gnome 3.26.2, if it helps for diagnostics :)

Comment: Maybe the double click speed is set to such a small value, so the system thinks you do click twice instead of a double click?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yay, great!

The problem was indeed the double-click delay (Activities > Universal Access > Double-click delay) set to zero. No X11 nor Wayland problem.