# how to disable mouse autoselect words when double clicking?

Tags: mouse

I have ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed on a Lenovo ideapad 110-15ACL. My mouse auto selects entire words when I do a double left click, in all applications (writer, gedit, etc.). I would like to deactivate this. I tried two things, without result.

1. I went to System Settings>Universal Access>Pointing and Clicking, and tried to disable the "hover click" and the "simulated secondary click" features. But Actually it was impossible to keep them in the "off" position : I turn them off, then go back to "All settings", then back again to "System Settings>Universal Access>Pointing and Clicking", and discover that they were automatically turned on again. Seems there is a bug there.
2. I also went to gnome-tweak-tool, but no option appears for that auto select thing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, triple click selects an entire line or paragraph. If this doesn't help, you should doubt your mouse key is not chattering. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002145/cant-select-text-on-double-or-triple-click

Comment: Check this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45925/how-to-configure-the-double-click-behavior-in-an-x-terminal

Comment: @Sadaharu Wakisaka. Thank you for that answer. If I set the double clicking speed to the "fastest" position, it works. But it affects the mouse for all other uses, not only for working in text editors. So I have to change the setting as soon as I want to use the mouse in another software. This is annoying. So I would like to cancel specifically the "double click" or "triple click" functionality of the mouse, not its reaction time.

Comment: @amphyschim, that's one of concerns I was worrying, you can cancel the double-triple  click to highlight select feature in a particular application, if you choose the editor like nano or vim, post of vanadium link would help. You can disable highlight feature entirely OS level but you need to change a lot of places in deep level of OS codes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575758/conventions-for-the-behavior-of-double-or-triple-click-to-select-text-features